# Remove call out/pop up from timeline blocks

Tags: tasks, task-list, popup, timeline, callouts

I have looked around for a solution and can't seem to find anything about this.

I have a task list with the timeline enabled. All tasks have been added to timeline as bars. I have used some CSS to hide the list below the timeline so only the timeline is visible.

What I want to do is remove the pop up/call out that appears when clicking on these blocks (Open, Edit Date Range, Remove from timeline). It seems unnecessary as all the options are available in the ribbon so I want to be able to click one of the bars and it take me directly to the display form.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if it is how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is changing the users' permission an option?  If they have read-only permissions Sharepoint might not display the other options you describe.   I appreciate it is a task list and normally everyone needs to be able to keep tasks updated, which would mean they would need the Contribute permissions normally.  However, I've been involved in projects sometimes where the Project Manager will lead the meeting and edit the tasks based on the participants' verbal comments (participant = Assigned To).

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is a sub-site that will only be used by people involved in the projects who will need to keep going in and updating/attaching documents etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to intercept the event that pops up that interface. I've never tried it, but all of the bars on the timeline have class `js-callout-launchPoint` and `ms-tl-bar` - maybe you could add some javascript to attach a new event to those classes. There are already events on that div for blur, dblclick, focus, mousedown, mouseout, and mouseover.

To test, what I'd do is create a wiki page and put the timeline there - there's a webpart that's just a timeline - once you add it you select which timeline you want to show. No need for CSS to hide the rest of the view. Then you can add script to the page to test out the functionality without messing around with any of the other task views.

I've saved a site that talks about modifying callouts but I've never tried it - it has javascript code to build up the callup window, and it references another page of info as well.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/01/02/create-calloutactions-in-hover-overcallout-popups-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/07/08/hideremovecustomize-callout-actions-in-sharepoint-2013/

Those talk about using the CalloutManager that's located in callout.js - a standard SharePoint library.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've followed the guide but this doesn't seem to effect the timeline it instead included a list of clickable icons beneath the timeline that need to be clicked to open the call out. I tried messing around with it a little and have managed to use the logic to find a way to remove the callouts.

Comment: Glad your persistence paid off - good job!